# jquery,prototype,mootools altogether in magento

Tags: jquery, magento, mootools, prototypejs, javascript-framework

I have got a template which is really nice with great Ui. But they used jquery and mootools without any prob. And now i incorporate that one with magento but i have the prob with prototype. Is it possible to use all these libraries together. Please help me.

And one query with stackoverflow : here i had more than 110 reputation but certainly today i see only 1. I dont know why?

Thanks

Comment: hi @Jonathan i could see the history. But i couldnot understand why the system has withdrawn 100 points from my account. I could see -- 2010-10-13 rep 0     = 103       
 2   3927685 (5)
 1   3938633 (2)
-- 2010-10-15 rep +7    = 110       
 12  3943841 (-100)
-- 2010-10-16 rep -100  = 10        

** total rep 10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mootools and Prototype don't play well with each other.
The idea of having 3 full featured frameworks as well as including all the core Magento scripts with Scriptaculous - you're starting to get out of hand. You're duplicating functionality 3x over, all at the users experience detriment.

The only reason I can see to have to use all three libraries - would be because of various "plugins" available in each.  To that reason, there's a ton of "plugin" overlap out there.  Uplodify, and Harolds Mootools Uploader are more or less the same thing.  A good goal would be to start consolidating your third-party plugins under one library.  For maintainability, as well as for the betterment of the users experience (downloading 1+megs of javascript is just cruel for ecommerce).

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to get prototype / mootools (which are distantly related) to work with JQuery because the former two redefine the underlying DOM, and there are other clashes between them.  There's an article on how to how to work with moo/proto and JQuery [here](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools), see this [framework comparision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) for more details on which frameworks extend the dom (look at the "Dom Unextended" category)